# Importing JSONObject throw "not found" error

Tags: javascript, c#, json, unity-game-engine, import

Today I started searching on internet for Unity Runtime Level Editor and I finally find [OpenED](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/opened-open-source-runtime-editor-for-unity.247763/). I imported it in Unity and imported all requirements, but [JSONObject](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject) don´t want to cooperate.

[image: screenshot]

It throw errors like this:

```
Assets/Plugins/OpenEd/Inspectors/OEPropertiesInspector.js(16,35): BCE0018: The name 'JSONObject' does not denote a valid type ('not found').
```

What I tried:

- I go to asset store and download [JSONObject](http://JSONObject)
- I tried to paste JSONObject script in same directory as scripts causing errors
- I tried restarting Unity

Please can you write some of ideas, what can cause this errors?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example piece of code causing error:

```
for ( var i : int = 0; i < properties.data.list.Count; i++ ) {
            var obj : JSONObject = properties.data.list[i];

            obj.type = Popup ( "", obj.type, System.Enum.GetNames ( JSONObject.Type ), new Rect ( 0, offset.y, 95, 16 ) );  
            properties.data.keys[i] = TextField ( "", properties.data.keys[i], new Rect ( 100, offset.y, 155, 16 ) );
```

Comment: Where did you paste the JSONObject  script? What is the name and extension  of the JSONObject   script? Delete the OpenEd plugin folder just to see if you still have error with the JSONObject  script.

Comment: @Programmer JSONObject in c# script, so it have .cs (JSONObject.cs). If I delete plugin folder errors of this type disappear, but new appear, because other files missing (in plugins folder).

Comment: Sorry. You have to create a new project and try the JSONObject.cs there to make sure there is no error in this file. If there is no error then JSONObject.cs is likely eliminated as the problem.

Comment: @Programmer No JSONObject is without any errors in new project. Here is that file: https://pastebin.com/tQyvJh23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a compile order problems that happens when you try to use a C# code from JS script because the OpenEd plugin is made with JS.

You want the C# script to compile first before the JS script.

Put the *"JSONObject.cs"* file in the *"Assets/Standard Assets"* folder. Create this *"Standard Assets"* folder if it does not exist.

Some would put it in the *"Plugins"* folder, but put it in *"Assets/Standard Assets"* folder since that compiles first and the OpenEd plugin is already in the *"Plugins"* folder.

You can find more info about this on the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html).

Comment: I am going to have dinner and sleep. I will try it tomorrow.